# embed a X11 window in a gtk+3 widget

Tags: c, linux, gtk, x11

I would like to embed a simple X11 window in a gtk widget.

- I have found this gist https://gist.github.com/pastapojken/69f1e223fd926425f7ae770a95ec79a2 which does almost but not quite what I am looking for: It allows to add gtk widgets inside an X window, not the contrary.

I don't know if I am being clear as I am quite a newbie in both X11 and gtk. So here is a quick schema:
[image: schema of the issue]

So is this even possible, any advice on how to make this work ? I feel like all I need to do is inherit from GtkWidget and set its GdkWindow to a wrapper of the XID like this:

```
win = gdk_x11_window_foreign_new_for_display(display, xid);
gtk_widget_set_window(myWidget, win);
```

But I was not sucessful this way, all I get is two top level windows as shown below.
[image: my unsuccessful attempt]

I am running Fedora 32 on X11, NOT wayland

thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.
* Originally I was trying to wrap a 3D editor and vizualisation library (opencascade, a CAD lib used in Freecad) around a gtk gui as a learning project. I kinda went down the rabbit hole from there ;)

* Actually my main goal is to learn about linux, gtk and x11 as I am a developper, have been using linux for the past 4 years and would like to get familiar with the inner workings.

* I am using GTK as my toolkit because it is the native gui for my os. I wouldn't consider switching the GUI as a solution.

Comment: I will look at this. But please consider that I am still a student (BAC+3 école d'ingénieur) even tough I have quite some programming background and am interested in research I don't think I have the skills for a research project yet.

Comment: But you could still call me. And I'll be teaching at some école d'ingénieur in two weeks....

Comment: Je vous appelle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221060/discussion-between-mathis-brossier-and-basile-starynkevitch).

Comment: It's reasonable to wrap an X11 Window in a GTK window. A number of libraries have APIs that are defined in terms of X11 Window objects. Problem is, it looks as if the window manager is re-parenting the X11 window, because it has (presumably) no parent when created. Can you control the parent of the X11 window? Otherwise I think you'll have to try to re-parent it at the X11 level, which may or may not succeed.

Comment: Yes that is my concern. @BasileStarynkevitch advised me to avoid if possible the X11 approach as is too low level for my needs. I am currently trying to shortcut the opengl calls from my lib to a GtkGlArea. If I don't succeed i'll reconsider the X11 approach. Thanks.